# Most efficient way to get index of a table from HDF5

Tags: python, hdf5, pytables, h5py, hdf

I have an HDF5 file containing pandas Series/DataFrame tables. I need to get (pandas) index of a table stored under a key in HDF, but not necessarily the whole table:

I can think of two (effectively the same) methods of getting the index:

```
import pandas as pd

hdfPath = 'c:/example.h5'
hdfKey = 'dfkey'
# way 1:
with pd.HDFStore(hdfPath) as hdf:
    index = hdf[hdfKey].index

# way 2:
index = pd.read_hdf(hdfPath, hdfKey)
```

However for a pandas Series of ~2000 rows this takes 0.6 sec:

```
%timeit pd.read_hdf(hdfPath, hdfKey).index
1 loops, best of 3: 605 ms per loop
```

Is there a way to get only index of a table in HDF?

Answer (score 2):

The HDFStore object has a *select_column* method that will allow you to get the index. Note that it will return a Series with the index as the values.

```
with pd.HDFStore(hdfPath) as hdf:
    index = hdf.select_column(hdfKey, 'index').values
```